# "SELECT INTO" with Java predicate

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using the JDBC-ODBC bridge to work with Access databases. I am trying to select all polygons from one database which intersect with a given polygon, and put them in a new table in a different database. I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Polygons IN targetDB
FROM Polygons
WHERE intersects(givenPolygon, Polygons.SHAPE)
```

where Polygons is a table of polygons with BLOBs (column SHAPE) representing the shapes, and intersects() is a predicate I have in Java which reads the BLOB into my own Polygon class and decides if the shapes intersect. The Polygon table has an ID column that I could select against. What is an efficient way to get this same effect?

EDIT: it appears JDBC-ODBC does not support SELECT INTO across databases, necessitating another library (I used jackcess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). I select everything using JDBC, and then using jackcess to filter rows as I copy it between databases.

```
Polygon givenPolygon = getInputPolygon();

// open source and get data with JDBC
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(src);
Statement s = c.createStatement();
ResultSet results = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table);

// open dest and copy/filter with jackcess
Database destDB = Database.open(dest);
destDB.copyTable(table, results, new ImportFilter() {
    @Override
    public List<Column> filterColumns(List<Column> cols,
                                      ResultSetMetaData metadata)
    throws SQLException, IOException {
        // get all columns
        return cols;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] filterRow(Object[] row) throws SQLException,
    IOException {
        byte[] blob = row[1]; // or whatever your schema requires
        Polygon p = new Polygon(blob);
        if givenPolygon.intersects(p)
            return row;
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Insert A ResultSet from any JDBC driver is at http://www.hxtt.com/access/advanced.html#insertresultset